# How to insert an object into an array which is a field at a user-modified class? VBA

Tags: vba, excel, class, properties, private

I have a class that holds an array of pairs.

When I try to insert a new pair to that array I get an error message.

Why do I get that error, and how could I fix this?

```
'####  The class instance:  ####
dim pairsHolder as new ClassArrayOfPairs
pairsHolder.init(5)

'####  The pair instance:  ####
dim pair as new ClassPairs
pair.setLeft(4) ...      pair.setRight(7)  ....

'####  Trying to insert pair to array:  ####
Call pairsHolder.insertPairAt (0,pair)
```

That last statement raises an error:

> RunTime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the class:

```
'@@@@@  CLASS ArrayOfPairs  @@@@@
'--------------------------------
Private pairArr() As ClassPairs
Private maxPairs As Integer

'##### Initialize Parameters #####
Public Sub init(howManyPairs As Integer)
    maxPairs = howManyPairs
    ReDim pairArr(maxPairs - 1) As ClassPairs
End Sub


'##### INSERT pair #####
Public Sub insertPairAt(index as Integer, pair As ClassPairs)
        pairArr(index) = pair
End Sub
```

Just to clarify, `ClassPairs` is just an object with `Left` and `Right` field variables.

Comment: do you have a typo in the first line of code? your class doesn't appear to be called `ClassArrayOfPairs` but that's what sort of object you've created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to address your issue by simply adding `Set` before `pairArr(index) = pair` as such:

```
'##### INSERT pair #####
Public Sub insertPairAt(index as Integer, pair As ClassPairs)
    Set pairArr(index) = pair
End Sub
```

You are setting `pairArr(index) = pair`. `pair` and `pairArr(index)` are objects. Therefore, you need assign an object reference to `pairArr(index)` for it to be `pair` and `Set` is used to assign object references, [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement).

Comment: @TalKohavy No problem! Glad I could help!